# Ubuntu / Mint brightness 0 by default on login

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, brightness

Every time I boot up Ubuntu or Mint, after choosing an OS from GRUB menu, before logging in, screen brightness is set to 0. What is the reason behind that?

I always end up manually turning on the brightness in order to see the logo and then login screen. It does not happen in other distros like Debian.
I encounter this in Ubuntu 12.04, 13.10, Mint 15 and Mint 16.

computer specs:
Laptop Lenovo g500; intel celeron 1005M 1.9G; RAM 4GB; integrated graphics; win8/mint16 dualboot

Comment: You may have to edit your /etc/rc.local file to include or modify an entry like `echo 5 >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` in a case like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982078) or you may have for some reason an inappropriate acpi setting passed to a bootloader like grub in a case [like that](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=7528) maybe. You should also include in your question the brand of your graphics card and/or computer and specify if it's a laptop, as there's also the question of the specific driver if it's not simply configuration.

Comment: Thank You for Your comment I will check out what You said and add details into the original post

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not perfect solution. But you can give it a try

[how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

EDIT:
 Following command will do the job ( I tested it on my Desktop. Ubuntu 13.10 )

```
apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
xgamma -gamma .75
```

Here 75 is the percentage of brightness. Please note the leading "."
You can specify from 0.100 to 10.000

Comment: Could you copy the relevant details from that AU post to here so that this answer can stand on its own?

Comment: I tried that. 1) tried to install the package but it had been already present. 2) `xgamma -gamma` command set the brightness in current session only. After I restarted the machine, there was again black screen after OS selection. I should mention, it does not happen when I install OSs in virtualbox. machine is lenovo G500 win8/mint 16 dualboot

Comment: You can mention that command in one of the startup script to get executed every time. e.g. ~/.bashrc file.  For virtualBox solution, I have not tested yet. But, if `xgamma` is not useful the try `xbacklight`. Though, I am not sure about it